# Mautic Tracking JS and img return 404 on easy easyengine/nginx

Tags: mautic, easy-engine

I followed the instructions in [this](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-mautic-easyengine-ubuntu-16-04/) to install mautic on nginx server with eayengine. But both tracking file mtc.js and mtracking.gif return 404.

I have researched for a while but could not find any solution for this.

Please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Commenting on that tutorial might get attention of the author and you'd get a better answer.

Is the tracking pixel working if you add `index.php` in the URL like this example: `https://yourdomain.tld/index.php/mtracking.gif` ? If so, then double check that you did step 6.d correctly:

> Update the Nginx Configuration to fix a problem with Mautic accessing its assets when a redirect to the SSL site version is enabled.

```
cat "rewrite ^/index.php/(.*)$ /$1 last;" > /var/www/yoursitedomain.net/conf/nginx/urlfix.conf
```